# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: c#, datetime

I am  trying  to  convert from string to DataTime but an an error occurs.
I am using  VS 2003, .NET Framework 1.1

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("11/23/2010");
string s2 = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateTime dtnew = Convert.ToString(s2);
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Can any one  help me  me  with the  syntax  how  to  solve the error.

Comment: Strictly recommend you to switch at least to `.NET 2.0`. You will need VS 2005+. But you can use free VS 2010 which is anyway rather better than VS 2003!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
string input = "21-12-2010"; // dd-MM-yyyy    
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
{
    // use d
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I guess that you have made a typo - change `Convert.ToString(s2)` to `Convert.ToDateTime(s2)`.

Comment: i am getting an exception An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: when changed from change from                         Convert.ToString(s2) to Convert.ToDateTime(s2)

Comment: You better try with DateTime.Parse(). That will be absolve some of the errors. Seems like Convert() is crying on 11/23/2010 where it is thinking 23 is a month.

Comment: @prince23, that's because you are trying to convert from a date string that is not inline with your system culture. You should use DateTime.ParseExact method here where second parameter will be format of input string.

Answer (score 8):

You should be using `DateTime.Parse`, or `DateTime.ParseExact`.

```
DateTime dt= DateTime.Parse("11/23/2010");
string  s2=dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateTime dtnew = DateTime.Parse(s2);
```

Both have `TryXXX` variants that require passing in an out parameter, but will not throw an exception if the parse fails:

```
DateTime dt;
if(td = DateTime.TryParse("11/23/2010", out td))
{
  string  s2=dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
  DateTime dtnew = DateTime.Parse(s2);
}
```

Comment: 1. `dt = new DataTime`; 2. `dt = DateTime.Parse`; total: superfluous instantiation

Answer (score 6):

```
DateTime dtnew = Convert.ToString(s2);
```

problem is that your converting  `string s2` to string again and store it in `DateTime variable`

Try this:

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("11/23/2010");
string  s2 = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
DateTime dtnew = Convert.ToDateTime(s2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `DateTime.Parse(...)` or `DateTime.ParseExact(...)` if you need to specify the format.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Parse("01/01 2010");`
or use
`DateTime.TryParse`
if you aren't sure it converts every time, ie. not always a date, but sometimes blank.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
DateTimeConverter c = new DateTimeConverter();
DateTime dt = (DateTime)c.ConvertFromString("2012-05-10");
```

OR

```
DateTime dt2 = (DateTime)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dt).ConvertFrom("2012-05-21");
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to change double quotes (`""`) to single quotes (`''`)