# Importing data from Excel to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to retrieve data from Excel to SQL via MVC but I have issue with date time field because it get below error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'

[image: X]

my code in my controller:

```
public static string ConvertDateTime(string data)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        return DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "mm/dd/yy hh:mm"
            , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime)
            ? dateTime.ToString("mm/dd/yy hh:mm") : "N/A";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MultipleUpload(HttpPostedFileBase Excelfile)
    {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + Excelfile.FileName);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                Excelfile.SaveAs(path);
                //
                Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
                List<goldenfpcmap> map = new List<goldenfpcmap>();
                for (int row = 1; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    goldenfpcmap m = new goldenfpcmap();
                    m.InputDate = ConvertDateTime(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 7]).Value.ToString());
                    db.goldenfpcmaps.Add(m);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Action");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498206/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters `DateTime` format pattern "mm" represents minutes, whereas months are "MM". So instead of "mm/dd/yy hh:mm" you probably mean "MM/dd/yy hh:mm".

Second, the error you report suggests that property or field `m.InputDate` is expecting `DateTime?` but is getting a string instead. I'd recommend to refactor your convert method.

```
public static DateTime? ConvertDateTime(string data)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "MM/dd/yy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
        return dateTime;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mm for months was typo