# Cannot convert 'string' to 'System.DateTime' C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

Firstly, I want to say that I read many questions about similar problem and I couldn't find anything.
The difference is that I can't use `DateTime.Now` property, and I can't choose [any specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498206/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-datetime).

**It is on the user to choose one date from** `DatePicker`

I have tried Convert, Parse, tryParse, but still couldn't solve it...
This code will work fine if I use `String` in my class instead of `DateTime`, but I need to use `DateTime` type. Also, I don't want to display time, that's why I have formated like this. Can I get value to string, so I can parse it later?

```
string chosenDate = datePicker.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); //error
```

After that I thought to move value to my object. This is what I did:

```
newObject = new Classes.MyClass(DateTime.Parse(chosenDate));
```

I have lost all ideas...
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Sorry for too little information about problem.

The problem is that I have a DataGrid which has binding on DateTime date (in .cs). I tried this way because it won't show time, but if I apply the following it shows the time in my result as you can see.
[image: 2]

Comment: Why don't you simply use `datePicker.SelectedDate`? Like `newObject = new Classes.MyClass(datePicker.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault());`

Comment: @mm8 If I do that i get same problem

Comment: Where and why are you trying to convert the `DateTime` to a string?

Comment: To elaborate on what @mm8 is saying... `datePicker.SelectedDate` is returning a nullable `DateTime`.  `GetValueOrDefault` is converting that to a `DateTime`.  Why bother converting it to a string and then immediately parsing it back to a DateTime.  Skip the string part.  If you want to have it around as a string, do that, but keep the DateTime as a DateTime

Comment: @Flydog57 Can I do that with not showing time? That's why i tried this way.

Comment: As I menitioned below, Use `datePicker.SelectedDate.Date` to get the date. It will give you the DateTime at midnight (i.e. time 00:00:00) in the morning of the date the DateTime represents.  There is no "Date" type in out-of-the-box .NET.  The best you can do is pick a time that represents "no time" (which is what `.Date` does).  If you render a DateTime as a string containing no time part and then parse the string back to a DateTime, that's all you are doing.  If you want better time & date handling, consider Noda Time (but it requires somewhat more thought about what you are doing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `MyClass` expects a `DateTime`, you should use the value from the `DatePicker`'s `SelectedDate` property. It returns a `Nullable<DateTime>` that can be converted to a `DateTime` using the `GetValueOrDefault()` method:

```
newObject = new Classes.MyClass(datePicker.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault());
```

If there is no date selected, `GetValueOrDefault()` will return `DateTime.MinValue`.

The `DatePicker` doesn't store the date in any particular format. That's a formatting thing.

It doesn't set the time either. If you however set the time yourself, you could strip it away using the `Date` property of the `Date` time:

```
datePicker.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault().Date
```

Comment: Is it possible here to add some restriction for time? I mean to show only date?

Comment: Use `datePicker.SelectedDate.Date` to get the date.  It will give you the DateTime at midnight (i.e. time 00:00:00) in the morning of the date the DateTime represents.

Comment: How does a `DatePicker` show time? It stores a `DateTime` object but it never sets the time.

Comment: @mm8 I have dataGrid with binding on my DateTime Date in class. When I connect all this I get it's time. DataPicker doesn't show it but DataGrid does.

Comment: Then you should format the value in the `DataGrid` which is a completely different topic.